# Asymptotically, can supercomputers easily solve the Travelling Salesman Problem, why or why not?

Tags: data-structure

I just want to know if supercomputers could easily solve the TSMP or would still take a lot of time, as it does now?

Comment: Asymptotically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must understand that no classical computer in the world nor in the universe will ever solve a large TSMP.

Supercomputer are barely one million times faster than personal computers, this is nothing compared to, say $100!$. A supercomputer would just allow you to add a handful of points for the same running time.

Comment: So you are in the $P \neq NP$ camp?

Comment: @Ingix: ha ha ha.